# JavaScript: replacing object keys with an array

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and experimenting the things. I have following object:

```
  var data = {'name': 'john', 'old': 18, 'place': 'USA'}
```

How can I switch the keys of this object with the following array?

```
 var array = ['First Name', 'age', 'country']
```

To look following:

```
{'First Name': 'john', 'age': 18, 'country': 'USA'}
```

Comment: You'd need some kind of mapping; that you want to replace `name` with `First Name` and `old` with `age`, because property order ain't guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = ['First Name', 'age', 'country'];

var data = {'name': 'john', 'old': 18, 'place': 'USA'};

var keys = Object.keys(data);
var newData = {};

for (var a in array) {
   //using new obj
   newData[array[a]] = data[keys[a]];

   //editing same obj
   data[array[a]] = data[keys[a]];
   delete data[keys[a]];
}

console.log(data);
console.log(newData);
```

```js
var array = ['First Name', 'age', 'country'];

var list = [
    { 'name': 'john 1', 'old': 18, 'place': 'USA' },
    { 'name': 'john 2', 'old': 19, 'place': 'USB' },
    { 'name': 'john 3', 'old': 20, 'place': 'USC' },
];

var newList = [];

for (var item in list) {
  var newData = {};
  
  for (var a in array) {
     newData[array[a]] = list[item][Object.keys(list[item])[a]];
  }
  
  newList.push(newData);
}

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: Thats a brilliant answer. I ended up using the method with new obj. Just a quick question, do the new keys will maintain the same index as the old ones? What if I want to try this method on hundreds of items? Thanks a lot

Comment: I added an example with a list

Answer (score 4):

The only way to rename a key of an object is to assign the value of the old key to the new key and then delete the old key

```
Object[ new_key ] = Object[ old_key ];
delete Object[ old_key ];
```

Another way is to create a completely new object (with the new keys), assign the values to the new keys and then delete the old object.

Comment: but you said "How can I switch the keys of this object with the following array?", why so this is the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()`, `Object.entries()`, `.map()`, spread element and computed properties to assign the property name to a new object having value to to current index of property, value within iteration, set identifier for original object to result of `Object.assign()` call

```js
let array = ['First Name', 'age', 'country']
let data = {'name': 'john', 'old': 18, 'place': 'USA'}

data = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(data)
         .map(([, prop], index) => ({[array[index]]: prop})));
            
console.log(data);
```

Comment: for me this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `switching` the object keys; which cannot be done and you'd have to delete keys and add the new one, you could simply create a new object with the desired keys:

```
var data2 = {};
data2['First Name'] = data.name;
data2.age = data.old;
data2country = data.place;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with the replacement keys and iterate it for changing the keys.

```js
var data = { name: 'john', old: 18, place: 'USA' },
    newKeys = { name: 'First Name', old: 'age', place: 'country' };
    
Object.keys(newKeys).forEach(function (k) {
    data[newKeys[k]] = data[k];
    delete data[k];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: @Laurianti, you need some kind of relation. objects have no order and you can not rely on the order of the keys,

Comment: if you use Object.keys(newKeys) yes, if you use Object.keys(data) you have to save it first you change it

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {'name': 'john', 'old': 18, 'place': 'USA'}
var ary = ['First Name', 'age', 'country']

// create key-value pairs array 
var obj_entries = Object.entries(data)

var new_data =ary.reduce((acc, value, idx)=>{
                            acc[value]=obj_entries[idx][1];
                            return acc;
                             }, {})
console.log(new_data)
```

Maybe a functional approach

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to make a deep copy of values of object if the values contains any other object

```js
    let data = {'name': 'john', 'old': 18, 'place': 'USA'}
    let keys = ['firstName', 'age', 'country'] // 
    let values = Object.values(data)
    let newObject = {} 
    keys.forEach((element,index) => { newObject[element] = values[index] })
    console.log(newObject)
```